# Where to place WHERE keyword?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SQL and I'm trying to figure out where to place a WHERE clause as I have certain values I want to filter by in column two.

I want to fit something like this into the SQL below:
WHERE table2.column2 = 'filter1' OR 'filter2'

```
create table practice_table
AS SELECT  table1.column1, table2.column2, count(table3.column3) ColumnAlias
FROM practice1 table1
JOIN practice2 table2 ON table1.table1ID = table2.table2ID
JOIN practice3 table3 ON table1.table1ID = table3.table3ID
GROUP BY table1.column1, t2.column2;
```

Comment: Before the `GROUP BY`.  The `WHERE` clause goes just after the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table practice_table
AS SELECT  table1.column1, table2.column2, count(table3.column3) ColumnAlias
FROM practice1 table1
JOIN practice2 table2 ON table1.table1ID = table2.table2ID
JOIN practice3 table3 ON table1.table1ID = table3.table3ID
where  table2.column2 in ('filter1','filter2')
GROUP BY table1.column1, t2.column2;
```